# Sharepoint Access Denied to new site - I am the primary admin

Tags: sharepoint, wss

I keep getting access denied when trying to access my new site through a browser.

In central admin i am primary administrator of the web app, i can connect to it using sharepoint designer and edit files and save them. Just when i try to browse to the site i keep getting Access Denied.

Edit: How i created the site

In central admin i created a new web application (i was added as primary admin), than create a site collection (added as site collection admin), than reset iis, and went to access the site. I get access denied. However if i try to goto /_layouts/settings.aspx i have access to that, but when i click on some links there i get access denied. Going to the Users and Groups persmissions i am apart of the Site Owners group.

Answer (score 2):

Are you using the browser directly on the server and getting a 401.1 error?

If so, it's probably due to the Loopback Adapter issue.  More information and possible workarounds are here:

[You receive error 401.1 when you browse a Web site that uses Integrated Authentication and is hosted on IIS 5.1 or IIS 6](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/896861)

Comment: that is not the problem unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

I am having the same issue. Creating a new SSP / web application / site collection, but can get in with any account. I can also get directly in to /_layouts/settings.aspx and can even create new sites, but can't access them ..

Comment: Not exactly sure how I fixed the problem. I'm thinking it had something to do with the application pool / SSP service credentials, but I'm not sure.